# How to pass image data to a View as HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an image that I save in database as byte[] ImageData and string ImageMimeType. The saving operation is fine, my view has an HttpPostedFileBase field which it binds with no issue. I then break this property into ImageData and ImageMimeType and store them in the database.

My problem is when I want to display the image back to the view from the database. I now have the ImageData and ImageMimeType but have no idea how to re-build an HttpPostedFileBase from them so I could pass them to my view model.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You can't. The only way the value of a `HttpPostedFileBase` can be set is by a user clicking the input in a browser and selecting a file(s). If you could do it in code, it would be a massive security issue (imagine if you navigated to a web site containing hundreds of hidden file inputs with common file names (say `outlook.pst`) - it would start downloading files from your computer without your knowledge)

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by _I want to display the image back to the view_. If you want to display a (say) thumbnail of an image file, you would use an `<img src="..." />` element. Or do you want to display a link to download it? Or are you wanting to edit the file (delete it and/or replace it with a new file)?

Comment: @Stephen Muecke - you are correct, I did think about using <img src="..." /> but i also have the input file as required. So when i first populate the view model from the db, the HttpPostefFileBase will remain empty and the user would have to select a file to proceed. This way the system doesn't let the user to keep their exiting image. I hope I'm making sense.

Comment: No, your not really making sense :). In a `Create` view you might have a `<input type="file" />` to bind to a `HttpPostedFileBase` property (and initialize and save you data model in the POST method). In an `Edit` method, you might just display the name of the file they uploaded. But if you wanted to allow the user to update the image, then you would include a another file input so that in the POST method, your update the data model.

Comment: But by coincidence, I am at this moment explaining one of my GitHub projects that manages uploading, editing and downloading files, and you might be interested in reading the comments in [this chat session](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137038/discussion-between-sachu-and-stephen-muecke)

Comment: Thanks for the input @StephenMuecke. Your comment re Create/Update does make sense. I will check out the chat session comments as well.